# Elisp function to get path to file link target

Tags: org-capture, org-link

With the cursor on a file link, I'd like to set up an org-capture template which inserts the template into the target of the link.

I guess I add something like

```
(setq org-capture-templates 
   '(("m" "Topic"
       entry
       (file (get-path-to-link-target-at-point))
       "\n* Topic %?")))
```

to my init.el in order to achieve what I'm looking for. But I'm not able to code such a function `get-path-to-link-target-at-point`. So how do I get the file path of a link target at my cursor location?

Comment: Is the problem the coding part (about which I would recommend googling) or the fact that the `get-path-to-link-target-at-point` function is not "called"?

Comment: The function was not being called, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `org-capture-templates` is basically a series of forms that are not evaluated.  That is why you put the quote.

This means that in order to call that function you would need to add a comma to unquote and possibly a backtick.

This is what I do in mine code usually:

```
(setq org-capture-templates 
   `(("m" "Topic"
       entry
       (file ,(get-path-to-link-target-at-point))
       "\n* Topic %?")))
```

Hope it helps.